# difficult harmonic conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to first find c so that u(x,y) = $x^3 + cxy^2$ is harmonic, then create $v(x,y) $ so that $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ is holomorphic at z.

First, to satisfy laplace,

$ u_x = 3x^2 + cy^2 \rightarrow u_{xx} = 6x$

$ u_y = 2cy \rightarrow u_{yy} = 2c$

$\rightarrow 6x = -2c $

$\rightarrow c = -3x$

This gives me $ u = x^3 - 3x^2y^2$

But then when I use the partials for Cauchy-Rieman and integrate to get v, I keep ending up with $ v = 3x^2y - xy^3 + C$ which does not produce the desired partials!

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unknown $c$ is supposed to be a *constant*, not a function. Look at your $u_y$ again.

Comment: Arrrrrrrgh. Sleep deprivation. Thank you.